# __DIR__ and autoloading php

Tags: php, include, autoload, bootstrapping

I don't know if this is exactly a problem in autoloading, but I am having this problem, here is my code:

`index.php`

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/autoload.php';
```

Folder structure:

```
index.php
app/
--autoload.php
```

`autoload.php`

```
 function autoloader($className) {
    // List Directories to Autoload Classes
    $paths = array(
        __DIR__ . '/system/',
        __DIR__ . '/app/models/',
        __DIR__ . '/app/dao/'
    );
    foreach($paths as $path) {
        $file = $path . '/' . $className . '.php';
        if (is_file($file))
            include $file;
    }
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work even I do:

```
__DIR__ . '../system/
... et al.
```

Comment: What is the error? Best way to debug would be to var_dump($paths) and then see what the exact paths are.

Comment: it does not load the file,..

Comment: make it require_once, bet it throws an error then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DIR** in the autoload file will refer to /app.

try:

```
function autoloader($className) {
    // List Directories to Autoload Classes
    $paths = array(
        '../system/',
        '/models/',
        '/dao/'
    );
    foreach($paths as $path) {
        $file = $path . '/' . $className . '.php';
        if (is_file($file))
            require_once $file;
    }
}
```

If that fails start echoing out paths and dir to see if they are referenced properly.

Comment: this still don't work. I echoed it and says `../system/File.php` but still doesn't include it.

Comment: can you put your directory structure in the original question - we will be able to see where things are and remedy your problem

Comment: if its in the OP then you don't have a system or a models or a dao directory anywhere.

Comment: okay, it's working now... maybe I restarted the computer and somehow it works with this `system/`

Answer (score 0):

I would try it this way. 
Anywhere before the autoload.php is loaded (should be file which is always loaded, i guess in your case its index.php) i would define ROOT variable somwhere at begining of the script

```
/**
* Use the DS to separate the directories (just a shortcut)
*/
if (!defined('DS')) {
   define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

/**
* The full path to the directory which holds application files, without a trailing DS.
*/
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__)); 
}
```

and then in your autoload use ROOT

```
$paths = array(
    ROOT . DS. 'system' . DS,
    ROOT . DS. 'app' . DS . 'models' . DS,
    ROOT . DS. 'app' . 'dao' . DS
);
```

Comment: I wonder where did you get your code, haha,.. it's really similar to what I have before including the comments..

Comment: +1 I use DS and PATH_ROOT constants. Declare these in your bootstrap and you're good to go!

Comment: geez... you should read about why is global states are BAD.. one thing, is that '/' is cross platform, no need to use DS or DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR